# Android: Theme not being applied and style parent showing up in red

Tags: java, android, themes, manifest

The theme I created for my fragment isn't working. I'm getting a error message in red saying "Validates resource references inside Android XML file". I've assigned the right theme in the manifest too.
The styles file is here:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#3FF4CB</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

My manifest is here:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LaunchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PhysicsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_physics_fragment" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EconFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_econ_fragment" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChemFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chem_fragment" >
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:maxSdkVersion="23">
</uses-sdk>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you gonna use Android's resources, you should use namespace something like this:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
```